# Asymptotic density of an infinite union of subgroups

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, probabilistic-number-theory

Let $1 < a_1 < a_2 < a_3 <{} ...$ be a sequence of integers. For a subset $A \subset \Bbb Z$, denote by $d(A)$ its natural density (if it exists).

> Is it true that $$ 
> \lim_{N \to +\infty} 
> d\Big( \bigcup_{i \leq N} a_i \Bbb Z \Big) 
> = 
> d\Big( \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} a_i \Bbb Z \Big)$$?

The density of the finite union $\bigcup_{i \leq N} a_i \Bbb Z$ can be computed via the inclusion-exclusion principle, but it is not clear how it would relate to the density of the infinite union.

(It was already asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4629599/, but no answer is provided).

Comment: I know that the answer is positive if the numbers $a_k$ are coprime (I came up with this problem a few years ago). But I don't know what to do in the general case.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov: interesting! How do you deal with the case where the $a_i$'s are pairwise coprime? I only know how to proceed if $a_k$ is the $k$-th prime number...

Comment: I split into two cases: $\sum \frac{1}{a_k} = \infty$ or $\sum \frac{1}{a_k}< \infty$. In the first case it is easy to see that both sides are equal to $1$, while in the second case we can uniformly estimate $|\{n: n \le M, \,\, a_m \mid n\,\,\text{for some}\quad m \ge N\}|$ by $M \sum_{k = N}^\infty \frac{1}{a_k}$ which can be made less than $\varepsilon  M$ if $N$ is big enough. But in the general case it is possible that $\sum \frac{1}{a_k}$ is infinite but the densities are less than $1$, so the first case doesn't work.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov: thanks! How to you prove that the limit on the left-hand side is 1, in the case where $\sum_k \frac{1}{a_k} = \infty$? Do you use inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: Yes, basically $\sum \frac{1}{a_k}$ is infinite if and only if $\prod (1 - \frac{1}{a_k})$ is zero, which is one minus density. So we can take enough terms to make the product less than $\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: Ah see. This is lemma 10.15 in Rosen'sbook on "Function fields"

Answer (score 3):

It's false. Up to an (irrelevant) factor of $2$, I work with $\mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$.

The only ingredient needed is that $c_D \to 0$ as $D \to \infty$, where $c_D > 0$ is such that $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N}\#\Big\{n \le N : \exists d \in [D,2D) \hspace{0.5mm} \text{ such that } d \mid n\Big\} = c_D.$$

For a proof, see, e.g., [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0607473.pdf), which is probably overkill, but it shows $$c_D \asymp \frac{1}{(\log D)^{\delta_0}(\log\log D)^{3/2}}$$ as $D \to \infty$, where $\delta_0 := 1-\frac{1+\log\log 2}{\log 2}$.

Now, since $c_D \to 0$, we may choose (sparse) $D_1 < D_2 < \dots$ so that $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty c_{D_j} < \frac{1}{10}.$$ Now let $A = \{a_1 < a_2 < \dots\}$ be $$A := \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \hspace{0.5mm} [D_j,2D_j).$$ By the choice of $(D_j)_{j=1}^\infty$, we have, for any fixed $J \in \mathbb{N}$, that $$d\Big(\bigcup_{j \le J} a_j \mathbb{N}\Big) \le \sum_{j \le J} d(a_j\mathbb{N}) = \sum_{j \le J} c_{D_j} < \frac{1}{10}.$$ Therefore, $$\limsup_{J \to \infty} \hspace{1mm} d\left(\bigcup_{j \le J} a_j \mathbb{N}\right) \le \frac{1}{10}.$$ However, since $A \supseteq [D,2D)$ for arbitrarily large values of $D$ (and $a_i \mid a_i$ for any $a_i \in \mathbb{N}$), we have $$\overline{d}\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty a_j \mathbb{Z}\right) \ge \overline{d}(A) \ge \frac{1}{2},$$ where $\overline{d}$ denotes the upper asymptotic density of $A$.

Comment: Are you sure you estimated lower asymptotic density? It seems to me that your argument only shows that upper asymptotic density is at least $\frac{1}{2}$ (and with some modifications it can be made equal to $1$), but I see no reason why the lower asymptotic density should be big.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I see what you did there:)